# Oracle End of file ao executar procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

Estou tendo o seguinte mensagem de erro ao executar essa procedure

```
*Encontrado simbolo "end of file" quando era esperado:*

DECLARE
  -- LOCAL VARIABLES HERE
  I INTEGER;
BEGIN

  FOR NCM IN (SELECT * FROM NCM_NCM) LOOP

    UPDATE ADMPRODU A
       SET A.CCNCMPRODU = NCM.NCM_NOVO
     WHERE A.CCNCMPRODU = NCM.NCM_VELHO

  END LOOP

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltam dois ;

Verifique assim:

```
DECLARE
  -- LOCAL VARIABLES HERE
  I INTEGER;
BEGIN

  FOR NCM IN (SELECT * FROM NCM_NCM) LOOP

    UPDATE ADMPRODU A
       SET A.CCNCMPRODU = NCM.NCM_NOVO
     WHERE A.CCNCMPRODU = NCM.NCM_VELHO;

  END LOOP;

END;
```